# telegram api - doesn't work with thread

Tags: java, api, exception, serialization, telegram

I use telegram-api library. When I run app with the following main method:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Application app = new Application();
        app.disableLogging();
        app.createApi();
        app.login();
        app.workLoop();
    }
```

It works fine. But when I do that:

```
    //Somewhere else
    public void testRun() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("run");
        Application app = new Application();
        app.main(null);
        Thread.sleep(10*60*1000);
    }
```

It throws the following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "Scheduller#988181144" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.telegram.tl.StreamingUtils.writeTLString(StreamingUtils.java:125)
    at org.telegram.api.requests.TLRequestAuthSignIn.serializeBody(Unknown Source)
    at org.telegram.tl.TLObject.serialize(TLObject.java:46)
    at org.telegram.tl.StreamingUtils.writeTLObject(StreamingUtils.java:192)
    at org.telegram.tl.StreamingUtils.writeTLMethod(StreamingUtils.java:203)
    at org.telegram.api.requests.TLRequestInvokeWithLayer11.serializeBody(Unknown Source)
    at org.telegram.tl.TLObject.serialize(TLObject.java:46)
    at org.telegram.tl.TLObject.serialize(TLObject.java:34)
    at org.telegram.mtproto.schedule.Scheduller.actualPackages(Scheduller.java:388)
    at org.telegram.mtproto.schedule.Scheduller.doSchedule(Scheduller.java:406)
    at org.telegram.mtproto.MTProto$SchedullerThread.run(MTProto.java:704)
```

I use the code from telegram-bot project.
What's the problem? Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do when you write `app.main(null);` ?

Comment: I don't need any args for this program

Answer (score 0):

Probably you haven't set one of TLRequestAuthSignIn's fields (see 3rd line) phoneNumber, phoneCodeHash and/or phoneCode.